# Any problems mixing T568B Patch cords with T568A Premise wiring?

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling, utp, standardisation

I'm going to be running some Cat5E cables to have a more organized wired computer network at home. I'm going to be terminating the premise wiring at the jacks and patch panels based on the T568A standard. I chose T568A because:

1. It's specified for residential installations according to ANSI/TIA-570-C for residential structired wiring.
2. I'm also running new phone Cat5e for some phone lines and using
   T568A there, and I want to be consistent during the installation for
   simplicity and to be able to repurpose cables if I chose to later.
3. T568A matches line 1 & 2 pinouts for phones.

A lot of the patch cords I currently have are T568B, and I'd like to reuse some. Would that cause any problems?

For example a run might be.

```
Computer<->Patch cord (T568B)<->Wall jack (T568A)<->Patch Panel Port (T568A)<->Patch Cord (T568A)<->Switch Port
```

I can't imagine that it would be a problem, but I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a problem. You only need to be concerned that both ends of a physical cable (patch cord, horizontal cable, vertical cable, etc.) are terminated to the same standard.